# Push notifications (GCM) не работают в production

Tags: ios, objective-c, уведомления

Добрый день! Подскажите, не работают push notifications в production с GCM. Не приходят сообщения, но registration token приходит.  И в development пуши работают.
У меня возникли подозрения в том, что в GCM указан не тот сертификат. 
Вопрос:

1. Как я могу протестировать production push notifications в
   development? Читал что можно залить на testflight, но есть ли другой
   способ полегче?
2. Могу ли я отредактировать ad-hoc provisioning profile, когда апп уже находится на appstore?

Comment: 1) Нет.

2) Нет.

Comment: 1). GCM переехал в firebase, возможно с этим связано. 2). Подскажите при отправлении push уведомлений вы отправляете priority:high?

Comment: @rowwingman
1) Нет, у нас без firebase. 
2) Да, отправляем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выставил в коде условие:

```
    BOOL sandboxOption;
#ifdef DEBUG
    sandboxOption = YES;
#else
    sandboxOption = NO;
#endif

[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:instanceIDConfig];
self.registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                         kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@(sandboxOption)};
[[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:self.gcmSenderID
                                                    scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                  options:self.registrationOptions
                                                  handler:self.registrationHandler];
```

Благодаря этому, теперь будет автоматически выбираться APNS server. Для release - production, для debug - sandbox. Это может помочь, так как иногда можно забыть поменять опцию, и залить билд без работающих пушей, так как опция sandbox не работает в production.

Еще перезалил p12 для production и sandbox в GCM, который сгенерировал из сертификатов APNS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понял, что проблема заключалась в том, что был указан не тот p12 для production. Перезалив исправил ситуацию.